# Add vertical columns in horizontal RecyclerView

Tags: android, adapter, android-recyclerview

I created a `RecyclerView` horizontal on my project. I want  to have horizontal rows  with different sizes and multiple vertical columns and each contains a different number of rows, like this image:

[image]

The number  of horizontal rows is variable. Column number one can have four rows,column two can have three,four...Number of columns is also variable.

The result would be like a tv guide, the column is the channel and rows the emission.Only this is not a guide to tv xD

I've done the horizontal rows in this way:

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);

recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);


public class SimpleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SimpleAdapter.VerticalItemHolder>{

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(VerticalItemHolder itemHolder, int position) {
        Item item = arrayItems.get(position);    

        int width = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, item.getSizeRow(), root.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = root.getLayoutParams();
        if (params == null) {
            params = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(heigth, width);
        } else {
            params.width = width;
            params.height = heigth;
        }

        root.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
```

The result is like this image:

[image]

But I can’t get certain items are displayed in the vertical column. How is it done? thanks

Comment: Can't you just add multiple horizontal recycler views into a vertical linear layout?

Comment: I can't add vertical columns in a horizontal recycler view.I changed the picture to facilitate question

Comment: Absolutely, you need to set `layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);`.

Comment: You just use layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL); for each recycler view and add them to a vertical linear layout. I've done that already. Best practice would be to put the recycler views into a custom view, so you can simplify the adding process.

Comment: Oh and am I wrong, are your rows and columns texts switched?

Comment: The row can contain text or image and size is variable. The problem I have is that I want to put some items in other vertical columns. An example of what I would do something like [link](http://www.tvguide.co.uk)  I managed to show everything in a column, but I want to move some items to new columns.Thanks for your response

Answer (score 5):

Answered from [here](http://blog.sqisland.com/2014/12/recyclerview-grid-with-header.html) for using `Variable span size` in `RecyclerView`

Use `GridLayoutManager` instead of `LinearLayoutManager` as below:

```
GridLayoutManager manager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 3);
manager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
  @Override
  public int getSpanSize(int position) {
    return (3 - position % 3);
  }
});
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
```

Here, I have to explain few things. see below image-

[image]

1. In above code, the span size is 3. It means that the maximum number of columns you want in any row is 3.
2. In above code, the method `getSpanSize` returns the span size of the `position`.

Span sizes for Above code:

1. if position is 0, span size is 3
2. if position is 1, span size is 2
3. if position is 2, span size is 1
4. if position is 3, span size is 3
5. if position is 4, span size is 2
6. if position is 5, span size is 1
   ... and so on.

If you understood this, it might help you.

Comment: thanks, I edited my question adding information. My app would be like schedules tv guide. I can do something similar with gridview?

Comment: as per your updated question, you should follow this answer. check once if it fits your requirement.